# Regex to match texts between specified markers in a multiline string

Tags: php, regex

I 'm working on a regex to match the example multi-line input below. I have tried this pattern but it is not working:

`(^[A].*\n.*\nZ.*)[^A]`

What regex can I use to select texts BETWEEN two delimiters? **The markers A and Z are case-sensitive and start of line**.

```
Start Marker=A
Stop Marker=Z

---INPUT---
AThis is the first linea AA
Csecond line - today is a good day
ZC is the delimeter
AZThis A is the fourth line
Bravo 
Delta blah blah's test
Echo test test
Z The end of the second match
AAnother match here - the third one
CZharlie test--
Omega test
Zend of the third match...
------------

---EXPECTED MATCHES-----
[1] 
AThis is the first linea AA
Csecond line - today is a good day
ZC is the delimeter

[2] 
AZThis A is the fourth line
Bravo 
Delta blah blah's test
Echo test test
Z The end of the second match

[3]
AAnother match here - the third one
CZharlie test--
Omega test
Zend of the third match...
------------------------
```

Can anyone help me figure out the correct pattern?

Comment: PHP or Perl? The answer could be potentially quite different. And show the relevant code as well as the regex, please, so we know you've used it correctly. Lastly what does "not working" mean? You get an error? Or it doesn't match correctly. Give an example of an expected match and also the result you get currently.

Comment: Have updated the title and tags to clearly state what language I am using - apologies! @ikegami

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Activating multiline and dotall [modifiers](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) you could have that expression:

```
/^A.*?^Z.*?$/ms
```

Key points:

- Caret used with multiline (`m`) modifier ensures `A` or `Z` match only at the beginning of a line.
- Dotall (`s`) modifier makes `.` match all characters including newline.
- Use of non-greedy repetition (`*?`) to not go to far.
- `$` at the end allow to capture the whole line instead of just the character `Z`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ouNpQD/1)

---

Edit: Effectively with a double star, catastrophic backtracking is never that far. Let's build something stronger.

Add more [contrast](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html#contrast), [be explicit](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html#what_you_want), and [be possessive](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html#atomic)!

I ended with [`/^A(?>[^Z]*(?>(?!^)Z[^Z]*)*)^Z.*$/gm`](https://regex101.com/r/3Tje9h/1).

Let's decompose :

```
^A          # Match starts with an A at the beginning of a line.
(?>         # Matches the following as atomic and never come back to it!
  [^Z]*       # Matches any non Z.
  (?>         # Nested atomic group.
    (?!^)Z      # Matches a Z if not at the beginning of a line.
    [^Z]*       # Matches any non Z.
  )*          # Repeat this atomic group as much as possible.
)           # End of the atomic group.
^Z          # Matches a line beginning Z.
.*$         # Matches any character until end of the line.
```

Note that we removed the single line flag which isn't needed anymore.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and for the informative explanation! Your solution has been working for a while until recently, where parsing on a very large string is causing a **Catastrophic backtracking** issue. I was wondering if there's a way to avoid this issue. Due to the huge size of the string, you may view the input string and demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/5xxI1G/2). Thanks in advance!

Comment: The delimiters are fixed: `A` (start delimiter) and `Z` (stop delimiter), are case-sensitive, and start of the line. Thanks!

Comment: I just saw your updated answer above! Excellent solution and much faster! Wish I could upvote your answer 1000x! Thanks a lot @PJProudhon - you're a rock star! :)